# Android: Improving audio performance running in service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on a music player for android, loosely based on the AOSP music player project.

The audio runs in a foreground service, but I've found songs are occasionally 'skipping', small audible 'hiccups' in the tracks.

Are there any other ways to improve the audio performance? Are there ways to raise the priority of the service, or otherwise protect the audio stream?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've established since posting this that the majority of the issues were caused by having a custom ROM on my phone.